# Check if an array of NSDictionary contains a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

In my app I've to check if in an array of `NSDictionary` there are another `NSDictionary`. In other words, I made a **JSON** file and I store it in **Documents**.
 Now I'm parsing this JSON to insert a new entry, before I insert this entry in my JSON I need to check if the entry it's already stored in my file. I parsed JSON so:

```
// First I read the JSON file from the folder Documents
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dictContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
// Json parsing
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictData = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];
if (dictContent) {
  NSDictionary *sites = [dictContent objectForKey:@"sites"];
  NSArray *site = [sites objectForKey:@"site"];
  array = [site mutableCopy];
}
```

Then I've another `NSDictionary` (`dictForJson`) in which I inserted the data parsed from the HTML site, so now I need to check if the data in the dictionary `dictForJson` are still in the JSON file.
How I can check that?

The dictForJson has this structure:

```
dictForJson = @{@"name": htmlTitle,
                    @"src": path,
                    @"expiryDate": expireDate};
```

the NSArray site has this structure:

```
site: (
        {
        expiryDate = "29 Ago 2013";
        name = Sito4;
        src = "/Users/redoddity/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/2D9EBE71-4365-448D-8AD2-A08749B8DBC1/Documents/Sito4.html";
    }
)
```

Have you any idea?
I tried with `[array containsObject:dictForJson]`, but the NSDictionary isn't ordered so when I use this method sometimes returns 0 and other times returns 1
Maybe it's useful I build my JSON with the following code:

```
- (void)JsonCreateOrEdit {
    NSDictionary *dictSites = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *dictSite = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *site = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *dictForJson = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    dictForJson = @{@"name": htmlTitle,
                    @"src": path,
                    @"expiryDate": expireDate};

    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
    BOOL fileExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

    if (!fileExist) {
        [site addObject:dictForJson];
        dictSite = @{@"site": site};
        dictSites = @{@"sites": dictSite};
        // Creo il file Json
        NSLog(@"Il file non esiste");
        SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc]init];
        NSString *jsonCommand = [writer stringWithObject:dictSites];
        [CreateFile createFileIn:documentsPath with:@"data.json" andData:jsonCommand]; // This is a class method I made to create the file
    else {
        // Here there are the instructions to update the file data.json
         NSLog(@"Il file esiste");
    // Leggo il file json
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dictContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    // Faccio il parsing del json
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictData = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];
    if (dictContent) {
        NSDictionary *sites = [dictContent objectForKey:@"sites"];
        NSArray *site = [sites objectForKey:@"site"];
        array = [site mutableCopy];
        // Here I must check if in the array site there are the same information I'm trying to insert
    }
}
```

Comment: try NSPredicate..this might solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, what I can do with NSPredicate? I never used it.

Comment: Sounds like you should check if a dictionary containing identical keys and values exists. Predicates are one way. You can also compare first the keys and then the values for the keys. But you need to only really identify the simplest key value combinations that will be unique.

Comment: @uchuugaka I've an idea, there's a way to maintain a NSDictionary ordered?

Comment: @MartinR: I tried with `containsObject` but it returns 0 (NO). Do you think I should use `isEqual` method

Comment: @PaoloRobertetti: Do you look for an identical dictionary in the array (all keys and value identical)? Or do you look for a dictionary that has the same "name" as the given dictionary?

Comment: I just update my question with the method that create the Json and generate the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! :)
I made so:

```
{
        // Aggiorno il file
        NSLog(@"Il file esiste");
        // Leggo il file json
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dictContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        // Faccio il parsing del json
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictData = [[NSMutableArray  alloc]init];
        if (dictContent) {
            NSDictionary *sites = [dictContent objectForKey:@"sites"];
            NSArray *site = [sites objectForKey:@"site"];
            NSDictionary *dict = [site objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"dictForJson = %@\ndict = %@", dictForJson, dict);
            NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
            array = [site mutableCopy];

        }
```

And it works! Thank you for the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[c] %@", @"name", @"htmlTitle"];
NSArray *theFilteredArray = [mainArrayOfDictionry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];

if ([theFilteredArray count]){
    NSLog(@"Dictionay Exists");
}else{
     NSLog(@"Dictionay does not Exists");
}
```

In the first statement the first parameter is the "Key" and the second parameter is the actual value of the dictionay.

**I am Assuming following :**

```
NSDictionary *dictForJson = @{@"name": htmlTitle,
                    @"src": path,
                    @"expiryDate": expireDate};


NSArray *mainArrayOfDictionry = (

"dictForJson" : @{@"name": htmlTitle,
                    @"src": path,
                    @"expiryDate": expireDate};
),
(),
(),
(),
.
.
.
)
```

**Hope this will help you.**Array

Comment: What I should use where you put this `@"%K LIKE[c] %@"`?

Comment: @Xman: Have you tested your code? I might be wrong but I don't think that comparing dictionaries with `LIKE` actually works.

Comment: use as it is...it is predicate format specifier..
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795

Comment: I tested just now and if i try to log the count of the theFilteredArray it shoews me 0

Comment: dictForJson is ok, the array I should filter is made like this:
`site: (
        {
        expiryDate = "29 Ago 2013";
        name = Sito4;
        src = "/Users/redoddity/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/2D9EBE71-4365-448D-8AD2-A08749B8DBC1/Documents/Sito4.html";
    }
)` and I will filter it by using the name (the name should be unique)

Comment: hmm..I think this code wont work..becuase I am searching for a key "dictForJson" which contain the
@{@"name": htmlTitle,
@"src": path,
@"expiryDate": expireDate};

But you just have array of dictionaries.

I am editing the answer...hope this time it will work.

Comment: Same problem it returns an empty array. However I update my question with the method I used to build the Json and generate the file, maybe it will help you